# Question regarding using ++$ inside variable and than echoing it

Tags: php

I'm sorry for this stupid question, I'm a beginner in PHP and trying to learn it.

```php
<?php
        $stepcount = "0";
        $srt = 'SAYI ' . ++$stepcount . ' . ADIM<br>';

        echo ($srt);
        echo ($srt);
        echo ($srt);
?>
```

The result of this php script is

```php
SAYI 1. ADIM
SAYI 1. ADIM
SAYI 1. ADIM
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is

```php
SAYI 1. ADIM
SAYI 2. ADIM
SAYI 3. ADIM
```

I'm sorry for this incredibly stupid question, I'm trying to learn and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. It works when I directly echo ++$stepcount but it doesn't when I put it in variable and then echo the variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Variables are not "calculated" every time they are used, only when they are assigned.  Once you create `$srt`, the value doesn't change unless/until you _explicitly_ assign a new value.  That said, it seems like what you really want is a loop.

Comment: I'm fetching database results using mysql select command and than put it in array than echo it. Since database returns multiple results I want to add a number in front of each result. I think this is called loop in php, if that's looping yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve.  Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: So you probably want a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.  If you show your actual code, not just the example, we could probably give you a more precise answer (or find an existing answer to close this as a duplicate)